# how can I get the remote address when I receive message from syslog client by sprint-integration-syslog?

Tags: java, spring-integration

I want to write a syslog server using spring-integration-syslog.

I can open my port 514 to receive data from various clients, but I don't know their host address.

Actually,I can see some log output by UnicastReceivingChannelAdapter,but these info I cannot get throw code.
The only channel I can use is "PollableChannel",but I cannot get any host information from it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "host" field from the syslog message is available in the `SyslogHeaders.HOST` message header (`"syslog_host"`).

The raw `IpHeaders` (ip address etc) are currently not included; I have [opened an issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/issues/2874) to fix that.

Comment: Thank you for you kind.I've seen code changes on GitHub.

Comment: I don't know when the Maven library will update this version.

I'll try to compile the latest code and then use it. Thanks again

Comment: You can get a snapshot (5.1.4.BUILD-SNAPSHOT from https://repo.spring.io/snapshot). 5.1.4.RELEASE should be in maven central later today.